# StandardSQL NTH() and FIRST() functions for BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm starting out in BigQuery, with some experience in pSQl. 
The #legacySQL query I'm running successfully is:

```
SELECT
    FIRST(SPLIT(ewTerms, '/')) AS place,
    NTH(2, SPLIT(ewTerms, '/')) AS divisor
FROM (SELECT ewTerms FROM account.free)
```

The string values in the 'ewTerms' column from the table 'free' are single digit fractions, such as "2/4", "3/5", etc. This #legacySQl query successfully creates two columns from 'ewTerms', reading:

```
Row place divisor
1   3   5
2   2   4
```

I need now to use this column creation in a WITH function, so I have to switch to using #standardSQL. 
Can anyone tell me how I can call to the string's FIRST() and NTH() functions using #standardSQL? I've tried:

```
WITH prep AS(
        SELECT 
            SPLIT(ewTerms, '/') AS split
        FROM (SELECT ewTerms FROM accounts.free)
    )

SELECT 
    split[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] AS place,
    split[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] AS divisor
FROM prep
```

but this is wrong. Help anyone?

Comment: Can you explain how it is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear about what is wrong. This query works for me:

```
#standardSQL
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT '3/5' AS ewTerms UNION ALL
  SELECT '2/4' AS ewTerms
), prep AS (
  SELECT 
    SPLIT(ewTerms, '/') AS split
  FROM Input
)
SELECT 
  split[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] AS place,
  split[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] AS divisor
FROM prep;
```

The output is:

```
+-------+---------+
| place | divisor |
+-------+---------+
| 2     | 4       |
| 3     | 5       |
+-------+---------+
```

Using your original table, your query would be:

```
#standardSQL
WITH prep AS (
  SELECT 
    SPLIT(ewTerms, '/') AS split
  FROM accounts.free
)
SELECT 
  split[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] AS place,
  split[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] AS divisor
FROM prep;
```

Comment: My apologies, I should have clarified that the column ewTerms has over 200000 rows in it, not just 2. The two I show were just for the purpose of posing an example of what the string looks like. So distinctly mentioning all of the potential values would not really be a viable option for me!

Comment: I understand that, but what was wrong with the sample query that you shared? Does the one that I provided work? As you observed, the equivalent to `FIRST` and `NTH` is `[SAFE_ORDINAL(pos)]`.

Comment: For some reason the one you provided doesn't show the correct values from the fractions.. When I run it, and the list was what I showed before (3/5, 2/4) the results come back 2 and 4, 2 and 4..

Comment: That is not what I see. I updated my answer with sample output.